# Don't show attribute in product collection if not set

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

Hi basically I need to echo out all the products attributes in an order. I get all the attributes as follows however if the attribute is not set it says its getValue() is "No". The issue is some attributes are actually Yes or No soI can't see which are actually set and which aren't! Code below:

List attributes and values:

```
  $productId = 355;
  $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
  $attributes = $product->getAttributes();

  foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
  if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront()) {
  $label = $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel($product);
  $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
    echo $label . ': ' . $value .'<br />';
  }
  }
```

This then spits out the following where only Colour is actually set backend. Any that aren't set don't need to be shown here!

```
Colour: Silver
Restrictor: No
Brand: No
Length: No
Split: No
Stack Height: No
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
   $productId = 355;
  $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
  $attributes = $product->getAttributes();

  foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
  if ((string)$attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product) != '' and $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product) != 'N/A'):
  if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront()) {
  $label = $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel($product);
  $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
    echo $label . ': ' . $value .'<br />';
  }
  }
```

or in your `Mage_Catalog.csv` set empty values to this:

```
N/A,""
No,""
```